# Where does Windows 10 store the last visited files, recent folders, and frequent folders?

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

It seems there are more than one places where the visited files and folders are stored on windows 10.
This one I know, the *recent-folder*: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`
You find shortcuts to  the last visited files and folders there.

Say, you have the explorer (or any other program) pinned on your taskbar. When you right-click on it, you get a list of pinned folders  and recently visited folders (resp. files that can be opened with that program). They are still there, even if you have deleted the shortcuts from the *recent-folder*.

Where are these lists of files stored?
Is there a possibility to delete all the recently visited files of one program without deleting others (lets say remove the last listened songs without deleting the recently visited excel tables)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to be describing the [Most Recently Used (MRU) lists](https://itstillworks.com/mru-list-12213731.html). Windows and some applications store the MRU list in the Registry, though many programs (particuarly those designed for portability) use local text files. For example, *IrfanView* maintains its MRU in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\IrfanView\i_view64.ini`.

There are *many* MRU's in *many* different locations in the Registry, and there are MRU containers, such as "bags". Open one to read the details:

[image: Registry MRU]

An excellent free tool to review MRU's in files and in the Registry is [Nirsoft's Recent File View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html).
[image: Recent Files View]

Comment: That **Nirsoft's Recent File View** tool is a great one as you can delete missing files that no longer reside at that path while retaining all other files in your history. Saves having to completely clear out the whole recently used history

Comment: `BagMRU IS Explorer's index of saved  views, only recent In the sense that it's limited to 5000.

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1508491/653259) deals with application-specific MRUs. Paths you've entered into Explorer are stored elsewhere in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths
```